# Source for lighting candles in a circle being OK b'dieved

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, chanuka

I recently played a Chanukah quiz game with friends. One of the questions was "is it permissible to light candles in a circle". The correct answer was "yes, b'dieved". I have always heard that the answer is no, so that it not look like a bonfire.

What is the source for the lighting counting (after the fact) when done in a circle? (And is the quizmaster's assertion actually correct?)

Comment: Would this be worse than lighting one candle per house? Perhaps a circle fails at being Mehadrin (min haMehadrin).

Comment: What candlelighting does this apply to? Only Chanukah, or any?

Comment: @SAH Question is about Chanukah. What other candle lightings would there be where this is a concern?

Comment: @Scimonster Shabbos candles, candles by the bimah... Are you sure this issue doesnt apply there too?

Comment: A) what candles by the bimah? B) do we ever see that we're supposed to light in a straight line elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see משנה ברורה ס' תרעא ס''ק טז who brings from חי אדם explicit that so long as  there is space like the width of a finger and you don't put a covering on top of all the flames even in a circle is kosher.